# Multi-regional site, same language - Google penalization

Tags: google, search, internationalization

Let's suppose there is a company "acme", that ships products world-wide. They have multiple sites, for example there is a site for Australia - **acme.com.au**  and a site for UK - **acme.co.uk**. Both sites have lots of identical content on pages (index, about, some product pages...)

Will be these sites penalized in results of Google Search and what can be done if so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [this google webmaster's post](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en)

> if you're providing the same content to the same users on different URLs [..], you should pick a preferred version and redirect (or use the rel=canonical link element) appropriately. In addition, you should follow the guidelines on rel-alternate-hreflang to make sure that the correct language or regional URL is served to searchers.

So use hreflang to mark each version and canonical tags for the duplicate content.

Comment: I suppose that's not our case. We are providing same content for different users (Australia / UK). Not same content for same users acme.de vs acme.com/de as is described in link you provided. Thanks